# javascript for loop does not iterate all the element

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to add a div for each element in the `distinctCtyNames` array. However if I press the button once, it only create a few divs and I have to press the button multiple time in order to pop all the elements and make them divs.
When I use `for(i=0;i<length;i++){ctyName = distinctCtyNames[i] /*and create div*/}`, there is no such problem

my code is as following:

`<input type="submit" name="BtnLogin" value="addDiv" onclick="addDiv()" id="addDiv" style="height:26px;width:100px;Z-INDEX: 105; LEFT: 440px; TOP: 72px"/>`

and

```
console.log(distinctCtyNames);
for (ctyName in distinctCtyNames){
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        ctyName = distinctCtyNames.pop();
        element.id = ctyName;
        element.style['cssText'] = "width: 1000px; height: 400px; margin: 0px auto;"
        oContent.appendChild(element);
    }
```

Comment: Debug your code by stepping through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reassign the `ctyName` var inside the for loop by using the `array.pop` method.
`pop` will remove the LAST element in the array, while you iterate from the start, and when you remove the last element the array will change, thus not iterate the full array.
When you run your loop, the `ctyName` var will be set for each instance in the `distinctCtyNames` array.

```
 for (ctyName in distinctCtyNames) { ...
```

Could be written:

```
 for(var i=0,len=distinctCtyNames.length;i<len;i++) {
   var ctyName = distinctCtyNames[i];
```

Stop using the `pop` method in the loop, and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**: Reassigning values
You are iterating through the array using

```
for (ctyName in distinctCtyNames)
```

At the same time, you are removing elements from this array using and reassigning the `ctyName` value.

```
ctyName = distinctCtyNames.pop();
```

For example, you have an array:

```
['Toronto', 'Moscow', 'New York', 'Paris']
```

Your for-loop takes 'Toronto' and assigns it to `ctyName`.
Now, in loop you make `ctyName = distinctCtyNames.pop()` and `ctyName` becomes equal to `Paris`. You have lost 'Toronto' value.

That's why your loop misses some values. You shouldn't do this.

**Problem 2: Incorrect `for` usage.**
Also, when you iterate through an array with `for` loop, it iterates through keys. You should get the value using the key.

**It works fine:**

```
for (ctyKey in distinctCtyNames) // changed to ctyKey
{
    var ctyName = distinctCtyNames[ctyKey]; // get ctyName using array[key]
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.id = ctyName;
    element.style['cssText'] = "width: 1000px; height: 400px; margin: 0px auto;"
    oContent.appendChild(element);
}
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/am1e0neg/1/).

**However,** iterating through the array using `for in` is a bad practice.
Read more about it [at this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: It should probably be `element.id = distinctCtyNames[ctyName];` to get the element and not the index.

Comment: No, given that `distinctCtyNames` is an array [this will **not** work fine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Sorry. I didn't notice that the OP has an error in this place. Fixed it.